# How do I get IntelliJ to resolve Gradle dependencies for custom source sets?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dependency-management

When IntelliJ opens a `build.gradle` file it will generate an IntelliJ project with the Gradle dependencies resolved and added to the project scope. This works great for the "compile" source set and the "test" source set, however I can not get this to work for custom source sets.

I want to have IntelliJ resolve the dependencies for my `componentTest` source set. How do I tell IntelliJ to resolve these dependencies and add them to scope?

```
dependencies {
    // main source set, "compile" scope in IntelliJ
    compile(group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0')

    // test source set, "test" scope in IntelliJ 
    testCompile(group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11')

    // my custom source set, not added to any scope in IntelliJ
    componentTestCompile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring', version: '3.0.7')
}
```

***Details:*** IntelliJ 13.1.2, Gradle 1.11

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is described in Gradle user guide - http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html and http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html

You will need to add something like:

```
idea {
  module {
    scopes.TEST.plus += [ configurations.componentTestCompile ]
  }
}
```

to your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Thanks for adding documentation links!

Comment: as of gradle 3.1, I have [ configurations.testCompile ]. Thanks for the answer, though!