# Java project with Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA: cannot resolve symbol 'google' but project compiles

Tags: java, configuration, import, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a toy Java project set up with Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.2.  It compiles and runs fine, but the IDE highlights 'google' in

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
```

as red and warns "Cannot resolve symbol 'google'".  Any idea how to fix it?

I have tried 1) deleting `.idea/` and re-creating the project in IntelliJ IDEA, and 2) re-importing project from the manually created Gradle configuration file `build.gradle`, but to  no avail.

Comment: Look at the dependencies and artifacts of your IDEA project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get IntelliJ to resolve Gradle dependencies for custom source sets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538929/how-do-i-get-intellij-to-resolve-gradle-dependencies-for-custom-source-sets)

Comment: There is an "idea" plugin for gradle, see the question linked above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the depended packages need to be separately specified in IntelliJ IDEA in addition to `build.gradle` and explicitly added as a dependency. Namely,

1. download the `com.google.guava` package following [the instruction in documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/downloading-libraries-from-maven-repositories.html) -- I picked `com.google.guava:guava-base:r03` to download
2. follow the automatically-prompted window to add it as a project library to the Java project.
3. Specify that the Java module depends on the `com.google.guava` package in the project settings. See the documentation instruction ["Configuring Module Dependencies and Libraries"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Comment: Not sure if understood well but importing gradle project into IntelliJ works pretty fine - using of gradle wrapper is recommended.

Comment: doesn't this pretty much negate the whole point of using gradle?

Comment: This link solved the same problelm i was having https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html

Comment: This was the only solution/description that worked for me (IntelliJ 14.1.2): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31195053/2584278

Answer (score 61):

I think user Sap is correct, at least in my case. You should not have to manually add the dependency.

Did you change the dependencies in the gradle file without syncing intellij? Try this button:

[image: screenshot of sync button]

For more information, see:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html

Comment: This did not work for me. Only "Invalidate Caches and Restart" worked.

Comment: ^ File dropdown in IntelliJ

Answer (score 19):

Check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html).

You can simply open Gradle tool window at [ `View` ] - [ `Tool Windows` ] - [ `Gradle` ].

In the window, you can refresh by clicking refresh button.

All dependencies manually added directly into `build.gradle` file will be resolved.

Answer (score 11):

One of the solutions that worked for me after trying everything listed on the internet to solve this issue was to install the lombok plugin.

Got to File --> Settings --> Plugins and look for Lombok.

[Make sure the "Enable annotation processing" is ticked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObHxB.png)

Comment: Thanks for providing the link

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I have to do the following:

- close project
- close idea
- remove .idea project directory
- remove (idea.system.path) directory
- start idea

You can find your `idea.system.path` here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me with the exception that I didn't have an idea.system.path directory (v2021.2.1 Ultimate)

Comment: Same as @Pink 2021.3.3

Comment: Close Intellij and delete .idea directory worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

My Gradle project is using Intellij 2019.2.3, and `File->Invalid Cache/Restart...` doesn't work, but `View->Tool Windows->Gradle->sync(the circular icon)` works instantly.

Answer (score 4):

What helped me was checking "dependencies" in "project settings/modules" section. Apparently, Idea did not pick up them correctly.

Steps which worked for me:

1. delete all modules from "project settings/modules"
2. refresh the project from Gradle plugin - that triggers generation of modules

This trick helped me to get modules with correct dependencies generated.
Probably it happened because initially, I imported the project as non-Gradle one.

Comment: This was what did it for me too, for those who don't know, you can find this under
File -> Project Structure -> project settings/modules. Then just delete all the modules there.

Comment: I'll add the issue for me was that my project had a build.gradle in a subdirectory. It's an AWS Lambda project created by the wizard that got out of sync and I had to re-import it and separately add the subdirectory as a module.

Answer (score 1):

For those who tried the above suggestion by refreshing the gradle projects but didn't work.

I ran gradle build in the terminal successfully, but IntelliJ didn't work.
I clicked on the build icon within IntelliJ, wait for the build, and it works.

See screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Apache Beam sources) a `./gradlew clean` was needed.

Answer (score 0):

In My Case, I've Updated the Gradle version(module: project) from 3.2.2 to 3.5.2, and also there was a problem with the NDK file location it was on the wrong path, I've just switched it to the default NDK path, then invalidate and restart the project.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the wrong import.Check if you have right import. In case you have imported using:

```
import org.junit.Test
```

and you have `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` in class path, try importing with :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```