# IntelliJ can't resolve gradle java cross module test dependencies

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, gradle, module

IntelliJ 2016.1
Gradle 2.1

Everything works fine on the command line using straight gradle.

Project structure:

```
build.gradle
\module1\build.gradle
\module1\src\test\......
\module2\build.gradle
\module2\src\test\......
```

Module 2 is using test classes from module 1. IntelliJ the shows "Cannot resolve symbol" error.  Remediation action in IntelliJ is 'Add dependency on module', which does nothing.

If I manually edit the module1_text.iml file and add

```
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="module1_test" production-on-test="" />
```

Then it works for a little bit.

Is IntelliJ just unable for some reason to edit the iml file? Or is something configured in gradle incorrectly?

My build.gradle is including the test code in the following way:

```
testCompile project (path: ':modules:module1')
```

Comment: Just a minor edit to @capybaras ' SO question. We include the test code like so:

evaluationDependsOn(':modules:modulename')
compileTestJava.dependsOn tasks.getByPath(':modules:modulename:testClasses')

Comment: Are you using the idea gradle plugin? You'll probably need to add a rewrite hook to the project's iml files to add the dependency to the other project's test output. See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#idea_plugin) for some short examples of such hooks. We are using this here with the eclipse plugin which works very much the same...

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538929/how-do-i-get-intellij-to-resolve-gradle-dependencies-for-custom-source-sets?rq=1) question. This should be pretty much what you need to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to create a dependency to another project's test classes by following [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-declare-a-dependency-on-a-modules-test-code/7172/9) approach.

rootproject/settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'rootproject'
include 'module1'
include 'module2'
```

rootproject/build.gradle:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = "2.14" }


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    }
}
```

rootproject/module1/build.gradle:

```
configurations {
    testArtifacts.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier "test"
    from sourceSets.test.output
}
artifacts {
    testArtifacts testJar
}
```

rootproject/module2/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    testCompile project (path: ':module1', configuration: 'testArtifacts')
}
```

Everything works as expected after importing the rootproject with IntelliJ's gradle wizard.

---

**UPDATE:**

- Added rootproject's settings.gradle file

Comment: For Gradle 4+ using Java library plugin, replace `testRuntime` with `testRuntimeOnly` and `sourceSets.test.output` with `sourceSets.test.output.classesDirs`. Also, if you just need the test sources, and don't care about transitive dependencies, `extendsFrom 
 testImplementation` is a better choice.